# Hosting Angular application on AWS EC2 without nginx

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nginx

We have been working with angular application and we have to host it on AWS. So I just want to check whether we can deploy the angular application without `nginx` or not. This question arise after we deployed `node.js` application without any hosting tool. Initially we were using pm2 for that but later we have removed it for API part. So now want to check whether we can use angular application without `nginx` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can if the angular application is only static files (HTML, CSS) and your backend services are in other hosts.

You don't need to use any AWS EC2 for running the static web application, you should use AWS CloudFront and AWS S3 for hosting it. Doing this way is more performance and cheaper very much.

You can read more about it at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started-secure-static-website-cloudformation-template.html

Comment: No the application is not the static one. So in that case we need to use nginx right ?

Comment: Does the angular application need Server-side rendering (SSR) or anything else related HTTP server?

Comment: Yes we are fetching the data. And then we are triggering the data using triggers.

Comment: Your explanation is too short, not enough for me to understand your problem. your backend services are in with your angular application? I can help you but I need you to explain more details about fetching the data

Answer (score 0):

The state-of-the-art way of hosting Angular apps on AWS is S3 + CloudFront. I recently wrote a [guide](https://medium.com/@iggyblob/serve-static-sites-for-free-using-aws-s3-and-cloudfront-384a3f604d6b) on how to do so.

No need for you to manually set up nginx on EC2.